"Error: Cannot find module 'aws-sdk'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/index.js\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs" despite me adding a dependency to the sdk
I have upgraded my nodejs runtime on my lamdba function today from 10x (very outdated I realise) to 18x and I am getting the following error:
"Error: Cannot find module 'aws-sdk'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/index.js\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs"
I understand that any version above 16x has to include the SDK as a dependency which I have done as part of the package.json file below:
{
  "name": "service-now-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "zip": "zip ../service-now-api.zip -r ."
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.216.0",
    "@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner": "^3.216.0"
  }
}

I must be missing something I'm just not sure what, any help would be greatly appreciated
This Lambda is responsible for handling calls into a ServiceNow instance and so if the lambda fails the calls don't get through
Below is the code from the index.js which is relevant to the aws sdk:
const https = require('https');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const proxy = require('proxy-agent');

AWS.config.update({
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
    httpOptions: {
        agent: proxy(process.env.PROXY_URL),
    },
});


show the code, how you're trying to use aws-sdk? In AWS-SDK v3 it's different now, so, show the code that's doing that. Looks like you kept the old way of importing SDK?

This is taken from the index.js, it's a large file but I think this is the only but that is relevant:
const https = require('https');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const proxy = require('proxy-agent');
AWS.config.update({
region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
httpOptions: {
agent: proxy(process.env.PROXY_URL),
},
});

Edit your question to add that code. require("aws-sdk"); is the way it was done in v2 and does not work in v3. You need to update your code. For easier migration, check documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/migrating.html

Thank you, I have looked at that documentation a little but the problem is that I'm not sure how to change the code. It is provided by ServiceNow so I didn't write any of it

At a first glance, the imports do not match the dependency in package.json. Shouldn't it be require('@aws-sdk/client-s3') ?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
